# how to call another controller#action with params from a Rails controller (not a redirect)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'd like to support vanity_urls and currently am using redirects which works fine but would rather just call a controller / action / params like the commented out section:

```
class VanityUrlController < ApplicationController

  def index
    item=VanityUrl.where('url=?',params[:url]).first
    if item.urlable_type=='Location'
      location=Location.find(item.urlable_id)
      redirect_to location_show_path(item.urlable_id)
      # would like something like this
      #call controller_name: locations, action: show, params: {id: item.urlable_id}
    end
  end
```

Is this possible? Googling gave me a bunch of redirect sol'ns but would rather not redirect. How would this be done?

thx

Comment: Have you seen this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809028/whats-the-correct-way-to-run-one-controller-action-from-another-controller-acti - There are two solutions that might do the trick - (1) extracting your desired method logic into a separate file and calling it from both places and (2) creating an instance of your other controller and calling methods on that instance (seems like less code but conceptually messier)

Comment: thx, hmm... those look a bit unpleasant - I hope there's something a bit more elegant (that ? is 5 years old).